# Excel VBA RegEx Using * (asterik) + End-Points to Match Entire String

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Why does the following return "*DATA*" and not "_DATA_5252014_"?

```
Dim regEx As New RegExp
regEx.Global = True
regEx.Pattern = "_DATA_*_"
Name = "ECMOSSO_DATA_12312013_RESULTS_TBL"
MsgBox regEx.Execute(Name)(0).Value
```

I guess the documentation indicates that it matches what preceeds the *, but I was always under the impression that this regular expression would yield "_DATA_12312013_" and not "*DATA*".  Is there a way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently matching an underscore, the **preceding** — "zero or more" times.

Instead, use the token `.*` ( *any single character* "except newline" ). The greedy `*` operator will shoot to the end of the string, then backtrack to the last underscore so you would want to use `*?` for a [**non-greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) match meaning "zero or more — preferably as few as possible".

```
_DATA_.*?_
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sE0xJ2/1)